# I can't install basemap package

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycharm, package, matplotlib-basemap

I tried to work with Basemap packages in Python 3.x but, when I try to install the packages in my IDE Pycharm, it gives me this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Basemap (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Basemap
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Anyone knows how can I do to install that packages correctly?

(Python 3.x, Pycharm, Windows 10)

Answer (score 4):

You can read on their github that the package was deprecated and they recommended to use cartopy instead:

Source:
https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap

⚠️ Warning: this package is being deprecated in favour of cartopy.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into a similar problem and the above two solutions did not work for me.
And as you can see here https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/issues/72#issuecomment-301008464
It is no longer possible to install it via pip, rather try this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install basemap using precompiled windows binaries.

1. Download the basemap whl file that is most applicable to you from
   [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap).
2. Run `pip install path_to_the_downloaded_whl` on pycharm terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can install basemap library easily by conda. First of all, you must [install conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/), then you can create a virtual environment by `conda create -n bm python=3.6` (you can use any word you like to replace `bm`) and activate it by `conda activate bm` . When command line starts with `(bm)`, you can run `conda install basemap` to automatically install the library. After that, usually you can use basemap in your python code.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing all folders, editors or other functions that are currently using python?

I legit used 8 hours trying to fix this after an uninstall, where it had previously worked using pip. Writing "pip install basemap" worked when I closed everything (including jupyterlab, which has never been a problem with any other packages).

Comment: You can leave a comment on such an answer, not in the actual thread!